# wait for a function to complete before self execute

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, jsp, servlets

I have two functions: function1() and function2()
 both functions have ajax calls to servlet. Second function  using values from textbox which is updated by ajax call of function1(). NOw my problem is that function2() running before the text box getting updated. So please help me.

I have also used

```
$.ajax({
    url:fun1(row),
    success:function(){
         fun2();
    }
});

 function fun1(row) {
     $(".calclr").val("0");
     var acq = row.find('td').eq(3).find("input").val();
     var rate = row.find('td').eq(6).find("input").val();
     $("#txtcomp").val(parseInt(acq * rate));
     $("#txtsolatium").val(parseInt($("#txtcomp").val() * 0.3));
     var field = $("#PlotTable").find(".tabactive");


     $(".tabactive").removeClass("tabactive");
     // $(this).children("td").addClass("tabactive");
     row.addClass("tabactive");
     var caseid = $("#caseId").val();

     JSONAry = JSON.stringify({
         Caseid: caseid
     });
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'geturgord',
         data: {
             JsonArray: JSONAry
         },
         success: function(retn) {
             var obj = JSON.parse(retn);
             if (obj.success == "true") {
                 var damg = obj.arr;
                 var objdam = JSON.parse(damg);
                 var assmnt = objdam.assess;
                 var not4us = objdam.not4us;
                 var notus417 = objdam.notus417;

                 var comland = $("#txtcomp").val();
                 if (objdam.ordurg == "1") {

                     var start = new Date(assmnt);
                     var end = new Date(not4us);
                     var diff = new Date(start - end);
                     var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

                     $("#txtintrst").val(parseInt(comland * days * (0.12 / 365)));

                 } else if (objdam.ordurg == "2") {

                     var start = new Date(assmnt);
                     var end = new Date(notus417);
                     var diff = new Date(start - end);
                     var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
                     $("#txtintrst").val(parseInt(comland * days * (0.12 / 365)));

                 }

                 var awdid = $("#hidawdid").val();
                 var pltsl = row.find('td').eq(1).find("input").val();
                 var table = "surfdam";
                 JSONArry = JSON.stringify({
                     Awdid: awdid,
                     id: pltsl,
                     Table: table
                 });

                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: 'getAwdeePlt',
                     data: {
                         JsonArray: JSONArry
                     },
                     success: function(retn) {
                         var obj = JSON.parse(retn);
                         if (obj.success == "true") {
                             var surfdam = obj.table;
                             var objdam = JSON.parse(surfdam);
                             var damtot = 0;
                             $.each(objdam, function(i) {
                                 damtot = damtot + parseFloat(objdam[i].damamount);
                             });
                             $("#txtsurf").val(parseInt(damtot));
                             $("#txttotcomp").val(parseInt($("#txtcomp").val()) +
                                 parseInt($("#txtintrst").val()) + parseInt($(
                                     "#txtsolatium").val()) + parseInt($("#txtsurf")
                                     .val()));

                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Is `fun1()` an ajax call?

Comment: yes fun1() and fun2() both having ajax calls

Comment: Where in the code is the text box update done?

Comment: Please show the code to `fun1()`.  You cannot solve this issue without changing the code of `fun1()`.  You will to trigger the ajax call you show only after `fun1()` has completed either using its success handler or using promises.

Comment: I have updated. Please check it now

Comment: Have you tried using the `complete` field? You can read more about [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). There is also a way of executing a callback after the ajax has been finished using `.done()`

Comment: used this also    $.when( fun1() ).done(function( ) {
   fun2();
   });`

Comment: @Prasenjit - you can't use `$.when()` until `fun1()` returns a promise that is resolved when all of its work is done.  `$.when()` does no magic and doesn't know when ajax calls are done.  It requires a promise as its argument, not a function.

Comment: What is supposed to get passed in this field `url:fun1(row),` because `fun1()` isn't returning anything so you're passing `undefined` right now.

Comment: Try calling `func2()` inside the `success:` event of the last ajax call within `func1()`.

Comment: @niklas but i am using fun1() for other work too. so cant put fun2() inside that

Comment: @Prasenjit Okey, maybe you should try making the ajax calls within `func1()` none asynchronous. As such: `async: false`. That might make `func1()` finish completely before the `success: function() { func2() }` is called.

Answer (score 0):

This whole thing would probably be best done with promises, but you can solve it with less rewrite than that by adding a callback to `fun1()` that is called when it is finally done with all its internal work, the final data is passed to that callback and then you trigger the other ajax call from that callback.

I only changed the code immediately following the comments in this code:

```
function fun1(row, completeFn) {
     $(".calclr").val("0");
     var acq = row.find('td').eq(3).find("input").val();
     var rate = row.find('td').eq(6).find("input").val();
     $("#txtcomp").val(parseInt(acq * rate));
     $("#txtsolatium").val(parseInt($("#txtcomp").val() * 0.3));
     var field = $("#PlotTable").find(".tabactive");


     $(".tabactive").removeClass("tabactive");
     row.addClass("tabactive");
     var caseid = $("#caseId").val();

     JSONAry = JSON.stringify({
         Caseid: caseid
     });
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'geturgord',
         data: {
             JsonArray: JSONAry
         },
         success: function(retn) {
             var obj = JSON.parse(retn);
             if (obj.success == "true") {
                 var damg = obj.arr;
                 var objdam = JSON.parse(damg);
                 var assmnt = objdam.assess;
                 var not4us = objdam.not4us;
                 var notus417 = objdam.notus417;

                 var comland = $("#txtcomp").val();
                 if (objdam.ordurg == "1") {

                     var start = new Date(assmnt);
                     var end = new Date(not4us);
                     var diff = new Date(start - end);
                     var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

                     $("#txtintrst").val(parseInt(comland * days * (0.12 / 365)));

                 } else if (objdam.ordurg == "2") {

                     var start = new Date(assmnt);
                     var end = new Date(notus417);
                     var diff = new Date(start - end);
                     var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
                     $("#txtintrst").val(parseInt(comland * days * (0.12 / 365)));

                 }

                 var awdid = $("#hidawdid").val();
                 var pltsl = row.find('td').eq(1).find("input").val();
                 var table = "surfdam";
                 JSONArry = JSON.stringify({
                     Awdid: awdid,
                     id: pltsl,
                     Table: table
                 });

                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: 'getAwdeePlt',
                     data: {
                         JsonArray: JSONArry
                     },
                     success: function(retn) {
                         var obj = JSON.parse(retn);
                         if (obj.success == "true") {
                             var surfdam = obj.table;
                             var objdam = JSON.parse(surfdam);
                             var damtot = 0;
                             $.each(objdam, function(i) {
                                 damtot = damtot + parseFloat(objdam[i].damamount);
                             });
                             $("#txtsurf").val(parseInt(damtot));
                             $("#txttotcomp").val(parseInt($("#txtcomp").val()) +
                                 parseInt($("#txtintrst").val()) + parseInt($(
                                     "#txtsolatium").val()) + parseInt($("#txtsurf")
                                     .val()));
                         }
                         // call the callback to indicate that we are done now
                         completeFn(/* pass whatever data you want here */);
                     }
                 });
             }
         }
     });
 }

 // call fun1() and invoke our other ajax calls when it calls its callback 
 // to indicate that it is done with all its internal processing
 fun1(function(data) {
     $.ajax({
         url: /* I'm not sure what is supposed to go here */,
         success:function(){
             fun2();
         }
      });         
 });
```

FYI, I'm not sure what is supposed to get passed in the `url` field to your ajax call.  You were passing the return result from `fun1()`, but it doesn't return anything so I don't know what you intended to pass there.  If it's a value that `fun1()` calculates with all it's ajax calls, then you can pass it to the callback and it will be available as the argument `data` in the callback.

---

A promise version of this would look something like this:

```
function fun1(row) {
     $(".calclr").val("0");
     var acq = row.find('td').eq(3).find("input").val();
     var rate = row.find('td').eq(6).find("input").val();
     $("#txtcomp").val(parseInt(acq * rate));
     $("#txtsolatium").val(parseInt($("#txtcomp").val() * 0.3));
     var field = $("#PlotTable").find(".tabactive");


     $(".tabactive").removeClass("tabactive");
     row.addClass("tabactive");
     var caseid = $("#caseId").val();

     JSONAry = JSON.stringify({
         Caseid: caseid
     });
     return $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'geturgord',
         data: {
             JsonArray: JSONAry
         }
     }).then(function(retn) {
         var obj = JSON.parse(retn);
         if (obj.success == "true") {
             var damg = obj.arr;
             var objdam = JSON.parse(damg);
             var assmnt = objdam.assess;
             var not4us = objdam.not4us;
             var notus417 = objdam.notus417;

             var comland = $("#txtcomp").val();
             if (objdam.ordurg == "1") {

                 var start = new Date(assmnt);
                 var end = new Date(not4us);
                 var diff = new Date(start - end);
                 var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;

                 $("#txtintrst").val(parseInt(comland * days * (0.12 / 365)));

             } else if (objdam.ordurg == "2") {

                 var start = new Date(assmnt);
                 var end = new Date(notus417);
                 var diff = new Date(start - end);
                 var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
                 $("#txtintrst").val(parseInt(comland * days * (0.12 / 365)));

             }

             var awdid = $("#hidawdid").val();
             var pltsl = row.find('td').eq(1).find("input").val();
             var table = "surfdam";
             JSONArry = JSON.stringify({
                 Awdid: awdid,
                 id: pltsl,
                 Table: table
             });

             return $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'getAwdeePlt',
                 data: {
                     JsonArray: JSONArry
                 }
             });
         }
     }).then(function(retn) {
         var obj = JSON.parse(retn);
         if (obj.success == "true") {
             var surfdam = obj.table;
             var objdam = JSON.parse(surfdam);
             var damtot = 0;
             $.each(objdam, function(i) {
                 damtot = damtot + parseFloat(objdam[i].damamount);
             });
             $("#txtsurf").val(parseInt(damtot));
             $("#txttotcomp").val(parseInt($("#txtcomp").val()) +
                 parseInt($("#txtintrst").val()) + parseInt($(
                     "#txtsolatium").val()) + parseInt($("#txtsurf")
                     .val()));
         }
     });
 }


 // now invoke the right sequence of functions and ajax calls
 fun1().then(function(data) {
     return $.ajax({url: /* I'm not sure what is supposed to go here */ });
 }).then(function(data) {
     fun2();
 });
```

Comment: thanks i can use callback. what you really like to know about url. I want only to pass "data" variable to fun1().

Comment: @Prasenjit - what `data` variable?  Where does its value come from?

Comment: I have added a promise version of the answer.

Comment: thank you @jfriend00 i used async: false it solved my problem

Comment: `async: false` is generally a bad way to do ajax calls because it locks up the browser for the duration of your ajax calls and since you have multiple calls in a row, this would not be good.  Good asynchronous code is harder to write, but is the better way to code because it makes a much better performing user experience.

Comment: @Prasenjit - personally, I'd rather use the promise solution I put in my answer, but if you really don't understand how that works, then go with the callback solution.